# Probability puzzle involving maximization in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I was looking at the following brain teaser:

> You are a prisoner sentenced to death. The Emperor offers you a chance
> to live by playing a simple game. He gives you 50 black marbles, 50
> white marbles and 2 empty bowls. He then says, "Divide these 100
> marbles into these 2 bowls. You can divide them any way you like as
> long as you use all the marbles. Then I will blindfold you and mix the
> bowls around. You then can choose one bowl and remove ONE marble. If
> the marble is WHITE you will live, but if the marble is BLACK... you
> will die."
>
> How do you divide the marbles up so that you have the greatest
> probability of choosing a WHITE marble?

The answer is to put one white marble in one bowl and all the remaining marbles in the other bowl, giving a probability of $74.7\%$. However, who do we rigorously justify this ?

Let $x$ be the number of white marbles in the first bowl and $y$ the total number of marbles in the first bowl. The probability we are interested in (choosing a white marble in the whole experiment) is given by: $$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{2y}+\frac{50-x}{200-2y} .$$
We want to maximise this expression over $0 \leq x \leq 50$ and $1 \leq y \leq 99$ (when $y=0$ or $100$, the probability is $25\%$).

The maximum can either be in the interior or on the boundary. We would need to check partial derivatives that are :
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{y - 50}{(y - 100) y} $$ $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{50 - x}{2 (100 - y)^2}  - \frac{x}{2 y^2}$$

I thought this starts to be too serious for a small brain teaser. Is there any simpler way ?

Answer (score 1):

First note that the answer is awfully close to a theoretical optimum.  After all, if the bowls aren't perfectly balanced, one must be $<.5$ and the other $>.5$  and if you had $(.5, 1)$ the answer would be $75\%$.  So there's hardly any room for improvement.

More precisely, we clearly can't improve on the $1$.  Can we improve on the other?  For any $b$, number of black balls in the bad bowl, the best we can do is $w=b-1$, clearly.  Could we hope to do better by lowering $b$?  Well, let's look at the pairs $(b-1, b)$.  That gives probability $\frac {b-1}{2b-1}$ and it is easily seen that this is an increasing function of $b$.  Indeed:  $$\frac {b-1}{2b-1}=\frac 12 -\frac 1{2(2b-1)}$$

It follows that $(49,50)$ is the best we can do for the bad bowl.  As $(1,0)$ clearly gives the best result for the good one, we are done.